# how much space use an array variable

Tags: c, arrays, avr

In c ,How much memory consume an array,That is only one single array
 ie,`int a[0]`;    or `char a[0];`

I want to know it when the program writes on a paper  ,not at program running on compiler
Here I cant use sizeof function ,  my compiler is avrgcc ,

In the part of my program some where I require an array of `int a[13];`only

or Instead of `int a[13]; an` int `a[3];` along with an integer type additionally  ie, int i.

specifically I require 
if i require 13 integer array or 4 integer array along with an integer variables.

which is less memory used

Comment: Use `sizeof`.. and figure it out?

Comment: `int a[0]`, an array of size 0 is non-standard.

Comment: In many cases, prefer [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: AVRGCC should have `sizeof`, I see no reason to avoid it

Comment: then a[13] takes (13 * 4) 52 bytes ,but a[3] and int i takes only (3*4+4) 16 byte ,thanks i will choose the second option

Comment: "I require an array of int a[13];only or Instead of int a[13]; i only require int a[3]; but here also need an another int variable int i."   Eeeeh?

Comment: @girikks - You might also consider that a typical PC has at least 4,000,000,000 bytes of memory. If you are using 16 or 52 of those bytes is not all that important.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch dynamic allocation on AVR can be problematic. I depends.

Answer (score 5):

The size of an array is the sum total of the size of each element in the array.

For example,

- if the array size is 5
- the array element (type) size is 4 bytes

The whole array would consume *(size * `sizeof` individual element)*, i.e., in this case `5 * 4` == 20 bytes.

This is irrespective of the *usage*, i.e., how many elements you actually *plan* to use.

FWIW, a 0-size/ 0-length array is non-standard. [It's a `gcc` extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) for a particular purpose (*before the addition of flexible array member as a standard*) that supports a 0-sized array, but you better not reply on it.

Answer (score 0):

An int (integer) type variable has a size of 2 bytes, a char has 1 byte. In an array the size of array multiplied by size of variable according to its type will give you the size of the array.
And you can use the sizeof also.

Comment: `An int (integer) type variable has a size of 2 bytes`..sadly, not universally true.

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is tagged AVR though where it _is_ always 2 bytes. But it's such a bad question, we really shouldn't post any answers.